# Developing front end html/css for asp.net application with prebuilt binaries

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, deployment, build-process

Does anyone have any experience with setting up an asp.net web application project such that a non-developer such as a designer could work on this project without any Visual Studio or build tools?

Currently we are developing web projects where we are required to commit binaries along with source into version control.  Now I'm opposed to this practise mainly because I believe generated files shouldn't be stored in source control.  One of the reasons why they persist is so a designer can modify css and html without needing visual studio installed.

With our project, IIS is configured to run the website straight from the project directory.  I want to introduce a system with continuous integration but I'm not sure if there exists a solution that can check out the source code and also download compiled binaries of the project.  This way a designer can modify and commit css changes but still run the website within the project directory.

This does sound round-about, so any alternative asp.net workflow suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the whole Visual Studio to build your asp.net project, just write them a simple `.bat` that launches [MSBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k6kkbsd.aspx) and builds the site. It's installed along the .Net Framework, available on any machine. As for the script contents, this should be enough

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\4.0\MSBuild.exe /t:Clean;Build
```

So I'd recommend removing the binaries from the version control and instead checking-in this script and instructing UI designers to run it once when they update the code from the repository.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately it is very unlikely that we will discontinue committing the binaries to source control.